# Get data using xpath on the basis of background

Tags: php, html, xpath, domdocument

I've a `list` and I want to get `value(innertext)` to the each of the `td` using `xpath`

```
<td align="center" valign="middle" height="14" width="14" background="/images/arrows/green1.gif" class="MENU_month2"><span class="CALENDAR_CELL">13</span></td>
```

I want to get the value `13` from the above code using `xPath`

So far, I've tried this, but getting nothing

```
$elements = $xpath->query('//td[contains(@background, "/images/arrows/green1.gif")]');
echo trim(strip_tags($functions->GetHTMLFromDom($elements)));
```

and inside `functions class` I've this function

```
 public function GetHTMLFromDom($domNodeList){ 
        $domDocument = new DOMDocument(); 
        foreach ($domNodeList as $node) {

            $domDocument->appendChild($domDocument->importNode($node, true)); 
            $domDocument->appendChild($domDocument->createTextNode(" ")); 
        }
        return $domDocument->saveHTML(); 
    }
```

I want to get this value on the basis of `background` only.

Thanks.

Comment: So what do you get back from that query? How many elements are there in the returned `DOMNodeList`?

Comment: There can be up to 31 elements, but I'm getting nothing by this query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only change I'd make is to add the `/span` to the query, eg

```
$elements = $xpath->query('//td[contains(@background, "/images/arrows/green1.gif")]/span');

foreach ($elements as $span) {
    echo $span->nodeValue, PHP_EOL;
}
```

Demo here ~ https://eval.in/185108

#### Update

Given your code edit, is this what you're after?

```
$elements = $xpath->query('//td[contains(@background, "/images/arrows/green1.gif")]/span/text()');
```

Here, I'm directly selecting the text content of the `<span>` within the `<td>` directly in the XPath query.

Demo with lots of `<td>` nodes ~ https://eval.in/185113

Answer (score 2):

Just try to loop it if it contains several `<td>`'s. Example:

```
$elements = $xpath->query('//td[contains(@background, "/images/arrows/green1.gif")]');
if($elements->length > 0) {
    // if it exists
    foreach($elements as $td) { // then foreach td
        // get the node value of inside the span
        echo $xpath->query('./span', $td)->item(0)->nodeValue; // 13
    }

}
```